# Char decrementing php

Tags: php

I already know that the following code works well

```
<?php
$a = "A";
$a++;
$a++;
echo $a; // "C"
```

But how can I go back from `C` to `A` as `$a--;` doesn't seems to be working ? .

Comment: What did you get back ?

Comment: Note that such incrementation and decrementation is only of limited use, since it only makes sense to ASCII and ISO, so 7bit and 8bit encoded text. It leads to problems with UTF code (unicode) which is the majority of all texts these days.

Answer (score 1):

You can't decrement chars in PHP. IMO, you shouldn't be allowed to increment chars either, but that's just me. What you can do is this:

```
$a = chr(ord($a) - 1);
```

`ord`  returns an int (the ASCII value of the first char in `$a`), which `chr` then converts back to a string.

To show that you *know* you're incrementing a character, I'd also advise you to change `$a++`; to the more self-documenting:

```
$a = chr(ord($a)+1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use chr() and ord():

```
$a = ord("A");
$a++;
$a++;
echo chr($a); // "C"
$a--;
echo chr($a); // "B"
$a--;
echo chr($a); // "A"
```